# Angular input[type="checkbox"] doesn't getting checked in view though its value is true in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-bootstrap

When I click "Cancel" in modal window, checkbox is unchecked, but it has to be checked (scope.enabledLogin has true after "Cancel" button is pressed and modal window is dismissed). Why?

Jade:

```
.checkbox(ng-show="showEnabledLogin", ng-class="{'disabled': (!email.length || userForm.email.$error.email)}")
      label(for="enabledLogin")
        input(ng-show="showEnabledLogin", type="checkbox", id="enabledLogin", name="enabledLogin", ng-model="enabledLogin", ng-disabled="(!email.length || userForm.email.$error.email)", ng-change="showEnabledLoginModal()")
        span Player login enabled
```

JS:

```
scope.isEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked = false;
function checkIfEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked() {
        if(scope.isEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked) {
          scope.showEnabledLogin = false;
          scope.showInviteLogin = true;
          scope.enabledLogin = false;
        } else {
          scope.showEnabledLogin = true;
          scope.showInviteLogin = false;
          scope.enabledLogin = true;
        }
      }
var enabledLoginModal,
                modalScope;

      var isOpened = false;

      scope.showEnabledLoginModal = function () {
        if (isOpened) return;
        if ((scope.email.length || scope.userForm.email.$error.email)) {
          if (scope.enabledLogin) {
              debugger;
            var child = scope.$new();
            var extension = {
              cancel: function (e) {
                scope.isEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked = false;
                checkIfEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked();
                enabledLoginModal.dismiss(e);
                isOpened = false;
              },
              modal: {
                title: 'Please confirm'
              }
            };
            modalScope = angular.extend(child, extension);
            var modalOptions = {backdrop: 'static', templateUrl: 'app/player/edit/show-enabled-login-modal.html'};
            enabledLoginModal = Modal.custom(modalOptions, modalScope, 'modal-danger');
            isOpened = true;
            enabledLoginModal.result.then(function (result) {
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: its better to create a fiddle so it will be easy to fix

Answer (score 0):

Please find this in your above code  and there

```
 cancel: function (e) {
                scope.isEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked = false;
                checkIfEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked();
                enabledLoginModal.dismiss(e);
                isOpened = false;
              },
```

This will execute once your click on the  modal's  cancel button and then  you set

```
scope.isEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked = false;
```

that is reason it i will get unchecked also

because you  called

```
enabledLoginModal.dismiss(e);
                isOpened = false;
```

these lines your modal closing when you click on cancel . if I am not clear please create fiddle so can research more.

## khajaamin

Comment: According to this code, when scope.isEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked = false, then scope.enabledLogin = true: function checkIfEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked() {
        if(scope.isEnabledLoginManuallyUnchecked) {
          scope.showEnabledLogin = false;
          scope.showInviteLogin = true;
          scope.enabledLogin = false;
        } else {
          scope.showEnabledLogin = true;
          scope.showInviteLogin = false;
          scope.enabledLogin = true;
        }
      }

Comment: Guys, thank for your efforts, it was issues with scope. I used scope.object.field instead of scope.field and all works now :)